# Why My function doesn't work properly as a I want?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

Here, I want when I will click on `X turn`, all `gameDiv` boxes will be `X`. And when I will click on `0` turns it will be all `0`. but in my code When I click on `x turn` or `0 turns`, every time it is giving me `0`. I know this problem is happening because, in `divcall function`, `select0 function` is working every time. But I want to know how can I fix this problem? I want, whenever I will click on `X or 0` only `selectX` or `select0` function will work```. As I am learning javascript recently, So, I couldn't be able to find out the solution for this problem. Please help me to fix this problem. I am just stuck here.

```js
let num1='X';
let num2='0';

function divCall(divIndex){
    let childDiv=document.getElementById("div"+divIndex);
    
    selectX(childDiv);
    select0(childDiv);

}


//start & restart function

let startButton=document.querySelector(".buttonDiv");
let childStart=startButton.children;
childStart[0].addEventListener("click",start);
childStart[1].addEventListener("click",restart);

function start(){
    let closeElement=document.querySelector(".startAlert");
    closeElement.style.visibility="visible";
    closeElement.style.opacity="1";
}

function restart(){
    let restartDiv=document.querySelector(".container");
    let childRestartDiv=restartDiv.children;
    for(let i=0;i<9;i++){
        childRestartDiv[i].innerHTML=" ";
    }
}



//popup funtion
let parentOfPopupDiv=document.querySelector(".startAlert");
let childOfPopupDiv=parentOfPopupDiv.children;
childOfPopupDiv[0].addEventListener("click",close);
childOfPopupDiv[2].addEventListener("click",selectX);
childOfPopupDiv[3].addEventListener("click",select0);


//close function

function close(){
    let closeElement=document.querySelector(".startAlert");
    closeElement.style.visibility="hidden";
    closeElement.style.opacity="0";
}

//select x funtion

function selectX(childDiv){
    close();
    childDiv.innerHTML=num1;
}

// select 0 function

function select0(childDiv){
    close();
    childDiv.innerHTML=num2;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
   
    text-align: center;
}

h1{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container .gameDiv{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.container .gameDiv:nth-child(1),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(2),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(3){
    border-top: none;
}
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(1),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(4),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(7){
    border-left: none;
}
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(7),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(8),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(9){
    border-bottom: none;
}
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(3),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(6),
.container .gameDiv:nth-child(9){
    border-right: none;
}
.buttonDiv{}
.buttonDiv button{
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttonDiv button:nth-child(2){
    margin-right: 0;
}

.startAlert{
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.startAlert p{
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.startAlert h1{
    margin: 50px 0;
}
.startAlert button{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: #e1b9cb;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="div1" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(1)"></div>
        <div id="div2" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(2)"></div>
        <div id="div3" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(3)"></div>
        <div id="div4" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(4)"></div>
        <div id="div5" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(5)"></div>
        <div id="div6" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(6)"></div>
        <div id="div7" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(7)"></div>
        <div id="div8" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(8)"></div>
        <div id="div9" class="gameDiv" onclick="divCall(9)"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="buttonDiv">
        <button>Start</button>
        <button>Restart</button>
    </div>

    <div class="startAlert">
        <p>X</p>
        <h1>Select Your Turn</h1>
        <button>X Turn</button>
        <button>0 Turn</button>
    </div>
```

`Thanks in Advance`

Comment: Because you do `selectX(childDiv);` immediately followed by `select0(childDiv);`, so the second overwrites the first. The result is always 0.

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in particular, [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know that but how can I fix this problem and get my desired output that?? That is my question.

Comment: Yes, the question is not for SO. Your biggest problem is not with the javascript but with the concept of not having game model.  Try to read something on how to organize your code as Model, View, Controller. That will help quite a bit when solving such problems as yours.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question you need to handle the current player - `X` or `O`. It means you need to **hold** the current state.

1. You need an initial state for current player.

```
let player_x = "X";
let player_o = "0";
let toggle = false; // <--- Flag to toggle current player.
let current = toggle ? player_x : player_o; // <--- Current player.
```

2. On selection of turn you need to update the current player state.

```
function setCurrent(toggle) {
  current = toggle ? player_x : player_o;
}
```

You will call the above method on selection of the *turn* that is `selectX` and `select0`. Notice that for `X` the `toggle` parameter should be `false`.

3. On click of the `div` inside tic-tac-toe you add the current state in the `innerHTML` and toggle the current state.

```
function divCall(id) {
  let childDiv = document.getElementById(id);

  childDiv.innerHTML = current;
  toggle = !toggle;
  setCurrent(toggle);
}
```

This way you will not override the values and will have clear state for the current player.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-tic-tac-toe-9vubg

This is of course a quick and one way of solving this problem. You can always work on refactoring the code to work better.